# Detect intersection between two components in ReactJS using IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, intersection-observer

I am trying to implement an **intersectionObserver** to watch if a  isIntersecting, but specifically only with another

My Attempt :-

```js
export const Main = () => {
  const sectionRef = useRef(null);
  const { headerRef } = useContext(HeaderContext);
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState<Boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        // Update state based on intersection status
        setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting);
        console.log(entry)
      
      },
      {
        root: document.querySelector('.app-header'),
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.1, // Intersection ratio
      }
    );

    // Start observing the Section element
    if (sectionRef.current) {
      observer.observe(sectionRef.current);
    }

    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

My desired result is to receive a **true** value if at point the user is scrolling and the header component intersects with the target Section Component. I have set the root in the options object to a be the reference of the actual header. When I try to scroll down, the Observer is observing based on the scroll viewport and not with the header. I'm definitely missing some key logic somewhere. Any help would be great.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Next?  Or is it just a React/DOM question?  If you think Next plays a role, it would be good to add information on how to the question.  And if not, you should remove the Next tag, and update the title.

Comment: @MattMorgan, Sure, I changed to React